# How can I prevent background image on div from collapsing past a certain resize?

Tags: php, css

I'm building a Wordpress template (using PHP).

My basic page setup:

1. Nav bar at the top (not fixed there; disappears upon scroll)
2. 100% width picture w/ text typed over it (hence why I'm using a background image)
3. The rest of the content

My problem is when I try to resize the height of the window (make it smaller), the picture collapses, and leaves the words over it kind of out in space. How can I code this to make the background image shrink to contain the words, then stop shrinking when it gets there? (Image included at the bottom).

Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- div w/ BG image -->
 <div id="introParagraph" class="m-b-2 p-y-2">    
     <h1 class="text-xs-left col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1 m-b-1">Our <br> approach</h1>

<!-- Inner div that styles a paragraph inside pic -->        
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 m-t-1">
     <h3 class="text-xs-left" id="question">How we help you figure out what works for you and your business. <br><br> Click on the icons to learn more. </h3>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
 /******** MEDIA QUERIES *********/

@media (min-width: 650px){

#introParagraph{
  background:  url("../img/approach.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 45%;
}
```

Finally here's the full code with PHP:

```
<!--------------- Approach Intro -------------------->
        <div id="introParagraph" class="m-b-2 p-y-2">
            <?php
                if (have_rows('approach_introduction')):while(have_rows('approach_introduction')):the_row();
            ?>
            <h1 class="text-xs-left col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1 m-b-1">
                <?php
                    the_sub_field('page_header');
                ?>
                </h1>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 m-t-1">
                <h3 class="text-xs-left" id="question">
                    <?php
                        the_sub_field('page_description_paragraph');
                    ?> 
                    <br><br> Click on the icons to learn more. </h3>
            </div>
            <?php   endwhile;
            else :
                // no rows found
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
```

IMAGE TO SEE WHAT'S GOING ON:
[image: What's currently happening]

IMAGE TO SHOW WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE ONLOAD, WITHOUT SCROLLING DOWN (Except I want the horizontal nav in the white space above the big picture): 
[image: What's currently happening]

Comment: Can we please see what the nav bar looks like normally?

Comment: there's no php here

Comment: not enough code to support the question. You're using media queries but we have no idea what they do, so I'm out.

Comment: what do you mean `the picture collapses`, the image is only useful to me if I can see both states, before and after the `collapse` as it were.

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii- I added more code to hopefully show you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon, I think you want to set that inner div to position absolute and play around with it from there. You should set an ID for the inner div and then give it some attributes in your external css, including that position: absolute I mentioned. Make sure to add, position:relative; to your introParagraph div as well.